# Accessing the same instance of a class in another form

Tags: vb.net, class, singleton, instance

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I don't have enough experience to know the answer.  :)

```
DataClass, Form1, Form2
```

I have a public class, `DataClass`, in a separate file, `DataClass.vb`.  In `DataClass` I have data stored in several arrays that I need to access.  I have methods in `DataClass` so that I can access the data.  One of them is `GetName`.  Everything works fine on `Form1`.  I need to access the same data in the arrays on a another form, but I am required to call a new instance of the class, so when I call the methods to access the arrays, the data is empty.

I've seen some threads mention creating a `singleton class`, but most are about C# which I am not as familiar with.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Do you create an instance of Form2 from code running inside Form1?

Comment: xfx methods will work for you, but I'd suggest that you read some OOP tutorials/books. Because then you will get a deeper insight what it means to create a new object, to pass objects around via parameters, to have associations from object to others, and so forth.

Comment: @Steve - Yes, but just by calling the form name and .Show()

Comment: @Desty - Thanks for the advice, I think I should learn more on OOP to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can do this.
One of them would involve creating a `Module` and then making the variable that instantiates your class `Public` inside the module:

```
Module MyGlobalVariables
    Public MyDataClass As DataClass
End Module
```

Now, all the forms in your project will be able to access the `DataClass` via `MyGlobalVariables.MyDataClass`.

---

A preferable method would be to add a property to your Form2 that can be set to the `DataClass` instance:

```
Public Property MyDataClass As DataClass
```

Then, you would instantiate your `Form2` as follows (assuming the variable you use to instantiate `DataClass` in `Form1` is called `_dataClass`):

```
Dim frm2 As New Form2()
frm2.MyDataClass = _dataClass
frm2.Show()
```

---

And finally, another way would be to override the constructor of `Form2` and allow it to receive a parameter of type `DataClass`. Then, you could instantiate `Form2` as:

```
Dim frm2 As New Form2(_dataClass)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: The second method you provided is a perfect solution to my application.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a singleton class like this

```
Public Class DataClass
    Public Shared ReadOnly Instance As New DataClass()

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Other members here
End Class
```

You can access a single instance through the shared `Instance` member which is initialized automatically. The constructor `New` is private in order to forbid creating a new instance from outside of the class.

You can access the singleton like this

```
Dim data = DataClass.Instance
```

But this is not possible

```
Dim data = new DataClass() 'NOT POSSIBLE!
```

Since the singleton class is accessed through the class name, you can access it from the two forms easily.