# Excel VBA - Accessing the same class in multiple forms

Tags: excel, vba, class, userform

I am trying to modify the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419516/accessing-the-same-instance-of-a-class-in-another-form) to fit my code but I'm unclear as to where to place everything. I have a functioning class module: `CatchEvents` that works for `Form_Add_Product` and I want it to also work for `Form_Add_Inventory` which I already have created and really don't want to spend time recreating if I don't have to.

Here is the code that is in my `CatchEvents` class module:

```
Private Type GUID
      Data1 As Long
      Data2 As Integer
      Data3 As Integer
      Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
      Private Declare PtrSafe Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, _
              ByRef riidEvent As GUID, ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, _
              Optional ByVal ppcpOut As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
     Private Declare PtrSafe Function ConnectToConnectionPoint Lib "shlwapi" Alias "#168" (ByVal punk As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef riidEvent As GUID, _
              ByVal fConnect As Long, ByVal punkTarget As stdole.IUnknown, ByRef pdwCookie As Long, Optional ByVal ppcpOut As Long) As Long
#End If 
Private EventGuide As GUID
Private Ck As Long
Private ctl As Object


Public Sub MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Select Case TypeName(ctl)
        Case "TextBox": _
            If Button = 2 Then Run "MyRightClickMenu"     '<--this works fine
    End Select
End Sub


Public Sub ConnectAllEvents(ByVal Connect As Boolean)
      With EventGuide
          .Data1 = &H20400
          .Data4(0) = &HC0
          .Data4(7) = &H46
      End With
      ConnectToConnectionPoint Me, EventGuide, Connect, ctl, Ck, 0&
End Sub


Public Property Let Item(Ctrl As Object)
      Set ctl = Ctrl
      Call ConnectAllEvents(True)
End Property


Public Sub Clear()
      If (Ck <> 0) Then Call ConnectAllEvents(False)
      Set ctl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the code in my userforms, which both have the same `Private AllControls() As New CatchEvents` line.

```
Option Explicit
Private AllControls() As New CatchEvents

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Code here

End Sub
```

Finally, here is the code that calls the userform(s):

```
Public Sub Test_Inventory()

Form_Add_Inventory.Show

End Sub 
 
Public Sub Test_Product()

Form_Add_Product.Show

End Sub
```

How can I modify xfx's ["preferable method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419516/accessing-the-same-instance-of-a-class-in-another-form) as he states below?

> A preferable method would be to add a property to your `Form2` that can be set to the `DataClass` instance:
>
> ```
>    Public Property MyDataClass As DataClass
> ```
>
> Then, you would instantiate your `Form2` as follows (assuming the variable you use to instantiate `DataClass` in `Form1` is called `_dataClass`):
>
> ```
>    Dim frm2 As New Form2()  
>    frm2.MyDataClass = _dataClass  
>    frm2.Show()
> ```

More specifically:

1. Do I replace `DataClass` with `CatchEvents`?
2. Is `MyDataClass` a system thing or do I need to rename that too?
3. Where exactly does the `frm2` code go? (`Form_Add_Inventory` in my case)
4. What's the significance of the underscore in `_dataClass`? Do I need to use `_CatchEvents` instead?

Please and thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `Public AllControls() As New CatchEvents`, placed in a standard code module (perhaps the one from which you call the forms) should do the job. Remove the similar line in the forms' code modules.

Comment: @Variatus- That didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to move `Private AllControls() As New CatchEvents` out of the user form to standard module and make this variable public `Public AllControls() As New CatchEvents`. Then in your user forms just access it from this common location.

Comment: significance of the underscore in _dataClass is none for you because the code example was written for VB.NET. In VBA variable cant start with underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I should admit to being out of my depth on this one. In fact, I just got stuck on a very similar problem and may drag for help here myself a little later. My setup does fire but only for the Change event. However, I can answer some of your detailed questions.

1. Yes. Replace `DataClass` with `CatchEvents` because that's the name of your Class.
2. `MyDataClass` is a property name that you can choose as it suits you. The difficulty is to avoid duplication of names and `MyDataClass` serves that purpose fine.
3. The way you call your forms is a little Spartan. Please consider the code below.
4. No. `_dataClass` has the leading underscore to differentiate it from a variable called `DataClass`. xfx says that's the name of the variable used in form1. I think it's equivalent to your `AllControls` variable.

(It appears difficult to get this site's software to format the code below as code.)

```
Public Sub Test_Inventory()
    Dim FormAdd As Form_Add_Inventory
    Set FormAdd = Form_Add_Inventory      ' the Initialize event occurs here
    With FormAdd
        .Show   
    End With
    Unload FormAdd
    Set FormAdd  = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now, if you had a Property Set procedure in your Form's code by the name of `MyDataClass` (or a suitable substitute) you could assign a value to it with code like `Set .MyDataClass = _DataClass` just before the `.Show`. A Property Set procedure looks like the Property Let procedure you have, without the procedure call in it, just assigning the value to the locally declared variable. In fact, I believe you use *Property Set* for objects and your *Property Let* procedure is wrong in this regard - but if it works ...

My problem with your code is that I don't understand the API in your class module I'm planning on researching if it solves my own current difficulty. I'm missing a sample of how you invoke the class in the code that you published. But I'm not sure that would tell me anything.